# Excel find the last negative number in row, return the number in adjacent row

Tags: excel

I have two rows of data like this:

```
      A     B     C     D     E
R1    0     -10   -10   -10   80
R2    0     -10   -20   -30   50
```

I want a formula to find the last -ive number in `R1` and I want to return the value in `R2`.

I know how to return the first +ive value like so:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH(TRUE, $A$1:$A$1>0,0))
```

How do I find the last -ive and return the `R2` value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LOOKUP` for this, e.g.

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:E1<0),A2:E2)`

Finds the last negative value in `A1:E1` and returns corresponding value from `A2:E2`

Comment: Just for clarification: the `LOOKUP` function searches left to right in a row and top to bottom in a column. 
Therefore **last** refers to the "most right" or "most bottom".
`1/(A1:E1<0)` returns `#DIV/0!` for all positive numbers and `1`for all negative
Since it can't find the lookup_value,`2` the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value. As stated previously "the values in lookup_vector are assumed to be placed in ascending order", therefore the last `1` is the result. 
If no negative number exists in the series `#N/A` is returned.